# Format String to Integer in java

Tags: java, numberformatexception

I am facing the below problem:

I will be getting values similar or of greater length compared to temp value :

```
 public class NumberFormat {
     public static void main(String arg[]){
     Integer numValue = null;
     String temp="5474151538110135";
     numValue=Integer
    .parseInt(temp.trim());
     System.out.println("--> "+numValue);

}
}
```

Please provide a solution.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "5474151538110135"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:60)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:473)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:511)
    at com.filetransfer.August.NumberFormat.main(NumberFormat.java:10)
```

Comment: the String is to big for an integer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`5474151538110135` is greater than [`Integer.MAX_VALUE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE). Use `Long.parseLong` instead or `BigInteger` if the input number is likely to grow significantly

```
Long numValue = Long.parseLong(temp.trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably beacuse the value is larger than max int value which is 2147483647.

```
System.out.println(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

You should parse it to Long which max value is 9223372036854775807.

```
System.out.println(Long.MAX_VALUE);
```

like this

```
Long numValue = null;
  String temp="5474151538110135";
  numValue=Long
      .parseLong(temp.trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend use BigInteger for avoiding errors

Advantage of BigInteger Class

Integer is a wrapper of the primitive type int.The wrapper classes are basically used in cases where you want to treat the primitive as an object for ex-trying to pass an int value in a method that would take only a type of Object in such a case you would want to wrap primitive int value in the wrapper Integer which is of type Object. To know specific advantages of Integer I would suggest you to take a look at the Integer api provided by Sun.

Now coming to the BigInteger, you would use it in calculations which deal with very large numbers.The use of BigIntegers is in Security where typically it is used for keys specifications.For more info on BigIntegers take a look at the following link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html

I hope the info helped you.